# Creating a new variable depending on the first marks of another column (pattern matching)

Tags: r

I'd like tro create a new column depending on the content of another.

Means:
If the variable starts with "TR01" I would like to have the entry "before" and when starting with "TR02" I would like to have "after" in the new column.

DF

```
VPN Group Variable Value 
1    G1    TR01_01   5   
1    G1    TR01_02   6   
1    G1    TR01_03   1   
2    G2    TR01_01   6   
2    G2    TR01_02   1   
2    G2    TR01_03   5   
1    G1    TR02_01   1   
1    G1    TR02_02   2   
1    G1    TR02_03   1   
2    G2    TR02_01   4   
2    G2    TR02_02   1   
2    G2    TR02_03   1
```

DF with the new clumn "new"

```
VPN Group Variable Value NEW
1    G1    TR01_01   5   before
1    G1    TR01_02   6   before
1    G1    TR01_03   1   before
2    G2    TR01_01   6   before
2    G2    TR01_02   1   before
2    G2    TR01_03   5   before
1    G1    TR02_01   1   after
1    G1    TR02_02   2   after
1    G1    TR02_03   1   after
2    G2    TR02_01   4   after
2    G2    TR02_02   1   after
2    G2    TR02_03   1   after
```

I was trying to solve the problem with:

```
tt<-transform(DF,G=ifelse(Variable=="^TR01","before",ifelse(Variable=="^TR01","after",NA)))
```

but it did not work, I only got NAs.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `grep` to find the substring and then either use `ifelse` or numeric indexing.  Here, I am assigning (`:=`) a new column (using `data.table` as it happens in place and should be fast)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, NEW := c("after", "before")[grepl("^TR01", Variable)+1]]
```

---

Or we can use `ifelse` with `transform` i.e. `base R` methods

```
transform(DF, NEW = ifelse(grepl("^TRO1", Variable), "before", "after")))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The setDT solution works very fine!